# Not able to display the error message using Formik and yup

Tags: reactjs

i want to display the error messagefor the validation check using yup and formik
if any validation fails i am not able to move submit it and it highlights the field failing the validation.In addition i want to display the validation errors.
i have tried everything using the function of formik to dispaly the errors but it is not working .kindly help with my code.

```
import { faCloudUploadAlt } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { error } from "console";
import { useFormik } from "formik";
import { FormikErrors ,FormikTouched} from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import { ErrorMessage } from "formik";
import { useEffect } from "react";

function SocialProfileForm({
  onNext,
  onPrevious,
  socialProfileData,
  setSocialProfileData,
}: {
  onNext: any;
  onPrevious: (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void;
  socialProfileData: any;
  setSocialProfileData: any;
}) {
  const handleAvatarImageChange = (
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
  ) => {
    const file = e.target.files?.[0]; // Get the first selected file

    if (file) {
      // Perform any necessary operations on the file (e.g., extracting file name, URL, etc.)
      const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      formik.setFieldValue("avatarImg", fileURL);
    }
  };

  const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    fname: Yup.string().required("First Name is required"),
    lname: Yup.string().required("Last Name is required"),
    role: Yup.string().required("Role is required"),
    bio: Yup.string().required("Bio is required"),
    workEmail: Yup.string()
      .email("Invalid email")
      .required("Work Email is required"),
    msg: Yup.string().required("Message is required"),
    linkedinUrl: Yup.string()
      .url("Invalid LinkedIn URL")
      .required("LinkedIn URL is required"),
    twitterUrl: Yup.string()
      .url("Invalid Twitter URL")
      .required("Twitter URL is required"),
  });

  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      avatarImg: "",
      fname: "",
      lname: "",
      role: "",
      bio: "",
      workEmail: "",
      msg: "",
      linkedinUrl: "",
      twitterUrl: "",
    },
    validationSchema: validationSchema,
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      setSocialProfileData(values);
      onNext(values);
    },
  });

  const handleNext = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    formik.validateForm().then((errors) => {
      if (Object.keys(errors).length === 0) {
        setSocialProfileData(formik.values);
        onNext(e, formik.values);
      } else {
        const firstErrorField = Object.keys(errors)[0];
        const errorField = document.getElementById(firstErrorField);
        if (errorField) {
          errorField.focus();
        }
      }
    });
  };

  const handlePrevious = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    onPrevious(e);
  };

  const handleChangeImage = () => {
    const avatarImg = document.getElementById("avatar-img");
    if (avatarImg) {
      avatarImg.click();
    }
  };

const getErrorClassName = (fieldName: string) => {
  const errors = formik.errors as FormikErrors<{
    avatarImg: string;
    fname: string;
    lname: string;
    role: string;
    bio: string;
    workEmail: string;
    msg: string;
    linkedinUrl: string;
    twitterUrl: string;
  }>;

  const touched = formik.touched as FormikTouched<{
    avatarImg: string;
    fname: string;
    lname: string;
    role: string;
    bio: string;
    workEmail: string;
    msg: string;
    linkedinUrl: string;
    twitterUrl: string;
  }>;

  return errors[fieldName as keyof typeof errors] && touched[fieldName as keyof typeof touched]
    ? "border-red-500"
    : "border-gray-300";
};


 

const getErrorMessage = (fieldName: string) => {
  const errors = formik.errors as FormikErrors<{
    avatarImg: string;
    fname: string;
    lname: string;
    role: string;
    bio: string;
    workEmail: string;
    msg: string;
    linkedinUrl: string;
    twitterUrl: string;
  }>;

  const touched = formik.touched as FormikTouched<{
    avatarImg: string;
    fname: string;
    lname: string;
    role: string;
    bio: string;
    workEmail: string;
    msg: string;
    linkedinUrl: string;
    twitterUrl: string;
  }>;

  return errors[fieldName as keyof typeof errors] && touched[fieldName as keyof typeof touched] && (
    <p className="text-red-500">{errors[fieldName as keyof typeof errors]}</p>
  );
};



  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex flex-row items-center mb-4">
        <label
          htmlFor="avatar-img"
          className="w-1/3 sm:w-1/6 mr-4 font-bold"
        >
          {/* <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faImage} /> Avatar Image: */}
        </label>

        <div className="relative items-end w-1/4 h-20 sm:w-40 sm:h-40 rounded-full overflow-hidden">
          <div
            className="image-box w-full h-full bg-center bg-no-repeat bg-cover"
            style={{
              backgroundImage: `url(${formik.values.avatarImg})`,
            }}
          />

          <label
            htmlFor="avatar-img"
            className="absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 p-2 bg-gray-700 rounded-full cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-800"
          >
            <FontAwesomeIcon
              icon={faCloudUploadAlt}
              className="text-gray-300"
            />
            <input
              type="file"
              id="avatar-img"
              name="avatar-img"
              className="hidden"
              onChange={handleAvatarImageChange}
            />
          </label>
        </div>

        <div className="ml-4">
          <button
            type="button"
            className="justify-end next w-24 sm:w-32 bg-purple-800 hover:bg-purple-900 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:bg-purple-300 font-medium text-white text-sm px-4 py-2 text-center dark:bg-purple-300 dark:hover:bg-purple-600 dark:focus:bg-purple-900 mb-4 sm:mb-0 mr-8"
            onClick={handleChangeImage}
          >
            Change
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="flex flex-row mb-4">
        <label htmlFor="fname" className="w-1/3 md:w-1/6 mb-2 font-bold">
          Name:
        </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="fname"
          id="fname"
          placeholder="First Name"
          className={`block w-1/5 mr-10 items-start px-4 py-2 border rounded-md ${getErrorClassName(
            "fname"
          )}`}
          value={formik.values.fname}
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
        />
 {getErrorMessage("fname") && (
  <p className="text-red-500">{getErrorMessage("fname")}</p>
)}
        <input
          type="text"
          name="lname"
          id="lname"
          placeholder="Last Name"
          className={`block w-1/5 items-end px-4 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md ${getErrorClassName(
            "lname"
          )}`}
          value={formik.values.lname}
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
        />

        {getErrorMessage("lname")}
      </div>

      <div className="flex flex-row mb-4">
        <label htmlFor="role" className="w-1/3 md:w-1/6 mb-2 font-bold">
          Role:
        </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="role"
          id="role"
          placeholder="Role"
          className={`block w-2/5 px-4 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md ${getErrorClassName(
            "role"
          )}`}
          value={formik.values.role}
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
        />
        {getErrorMessage("role")}
      </div>

      <div className="flex flex-row mb-4">
        <label htmlFor="bio" className="w-1/3 md:w-1/6 mb-2 font-bold">
          Bio:
        </label>
        <textarea
          name="bio"
          id="bio"
          placeholder="Bio"
          className={`block w-2/5 px-4 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md ${getErrorClassName(
            "bio"
          )}`}
          value={formik.values.bio}
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
        ></textarea>
        {getErrorMessage("bio")}
      </div>

      <div className="flex flex-row mb-4">
        <label htmlFor="workEmail" className="w-1/3 md:w-1/6 mb-2 font-bold">
          Work Email:
        </label>
        <input
          type="email"
          name="workEmail"
          id="workEmail"
          placeholder="Work Email"
          className={`block w-2/5 px-4 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md ${getErrorClassName(
            "workEmail"
          )}`}
          value={formik.values.workEmail}
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
        />
        {getErrorMessage("workEmail")}
      </div>

      <div className="flex flex-row mb-4">
        <label htmlFor="msg" className="w-1/3 md:w-1/6 mb-2 font-bold">
          Message:
        </label>
        <textarea
          name="msg"
          id="msg"
          placeholder="Message"
          className={`block w-2/5 px-4 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md ${getErrorClassName(
            "msg"
          )}`}
          value={formik.values.msg}
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
        ></textarea>
        {getErrorMessage("msg")}
      </div>

      <div className="flex flex-row mb-4">
        <label
          htmlFor="linkedinUrl"
          className="w-1/3 md:w-1/6 mb-2 font-bold"
        >
          LinkedIn URL:
        </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="linkedinUrl"
          id="linkedinUrl"
          placeholder="LinkedIn URL"
          className={`block w-2/5 px-4 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md ${getErrorClassName(
            "linkedinUrl"
          )}`}
          value={formik.values.linkedinUrl}
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
        />
        {getErrorMessage("linkedinUrl")}
      </div>

      <div className="flex flex-row mb-4">
        <label htmlFor="twitterUrl" className="w-1/3 md:w-1/6 mb-2 font-bold">
          Twitter URL:
        </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="twitterUrl"
          id="twitterUrl"
          placeholder="Twitter URL"
          className={`block w-2/5 px-4 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md ${getErrorClassName(
            "twitterUrl"
          )}`}
          value={formik.values.twitterUrl}
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
        />
        {getErrorMessage("twitterUrl")}
      </div>

      <div className="flex flex-row sm:justify-end mt-10 mb-10">
        <button
          type="button"
          className="previous w-24 sm:w-32 bg-gray-500 hover:bg-purple-900 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:bg-purple-300 font-medium text-white text-sm px-4 py-2 text-center dark:bg-purple-300 dark:hover:bg-purple-600 dark:focus:bg-purple-900 mb-4 sm:mb-0 mr-8"
          onClick={handlePrevious}
        >
          Previous
        </button>
        <button
          type="button"
          className="next w-24 sm:w-32 bg-purple-800 hover:bg-purple-900 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:bg-purple-300 font-medium text-white text-sm px-4 py-2 text-center dark:bg-purple-300 dark:hover:bg-purple-600 dark:focus:bg-purple-900 mb-4 sm:mb-0 mr-8"
          onClick={handleNext}
        >
          Next
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default SocialProfileForm;
```